# Difference of static const and static when returning a static variable

Tags: c++, static, constants, static-methods

It is best explained in code:

```
static Unit& None() { static Unit none(....); return none;}
```

What is the difference to?

```
static const Unit& None() { static Unit none(....); return none;}
```

Comment: Are you asking what the difference is between a `Unit&` and a `const Unit&`?

Comment: As @DrewDormann says, the `const` goes with the `Unit&`, not with the `static`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `static` in front of the function has a completely different from the `static` inside a function<sup>1</sup>. In particular, it is **completely unrelated to the return type**. The return type of these functions is the same as here:

```
Unit& None() { static Unit none(....); return none;}

const Unit& None() { static Unit none(....); return none;}
```

i.e. without the `static` qualifier.

Thus the difference is only between `Unit&` and `Unit const&`: the first allows modifying the return value, the second doesn’t.

---

<sup>1)</sup> For a class member, `static` means that the function cannot access instance variables and instance functions of the class; on a namespace-scope function, `static` means that the function symbol isn’t exported from the compilation unit.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a reference to a static object/variable. So it's possible to assign a value to the function and then change the value of that object/variable.

Second one denies to change the value of `none`:

```
static int& func1()
{
    static int a = 1; return a;
}

static const int& func2()
{
    static int a = 1; return a;
}

int main()
{
    func1() = 10;    // OK
    func2() = 10;    // error: assignment of read-only location
}
```